How do I shrink down an SSIS project of two million characters to a core size that chatgpt 4 omni can eat and digest to wrap it up in C# and UML?
I have an average sized SSIS project at hand that I want to feed to the GPT chat to get pure C# code for an SSIS Script component. I also want to ask the bot to show a range of UML workflows, and when that is done, I ask the bot to check any other overviews that may help understanding the project.
The wrapping up must be so good that pasting the wrapping up in a new chat window should be (almost) as good as pasting the full 2 million characters SSIS project. The next aim on top of that is to merge the project with many other projects that were wrapped up as well, altogeher in one go in one chat, which is not the question here, but the aim to keep in mind, see How do I merge scattered and intertwined projects from SSIS, stored procedures, and Access databases into one SSIS project with the help of a ChatGPT?.
All of the packages and meta files put together amount to a number of > 2 million characters. It is not a very big project so that I guess that you will ask this question for any SSIS project, since: entering such a vast amount of characters is not meant to be the way you should chat with the bot. You should ask small questions to get longer answers, not the other way round.
In my company frontend of GPT 4 omni, I cannot go over the border of roughly 500,000 characters, see How do I count the true number of characters (with any whitespaces) or words in a GPT Chat to find out the border of the chat size?. Therefore, I could split the SSIS projects into smaller slices to let the bot wrap it up. Yet:

There are intertwined setups that are scattered over the project. You can finish the puzzle faster and better if you know the image.
It costs far too many tokens and therefore money and energy.

A smaller SSIS code could be enough:

I know that much of the code is system code or overhead that is not fully needed to grasp the workflows - even if you ask the bot to dig deeper and show SQL code as well.
Many column properties do not need to be known to the bot since you can handle them afterwards and they do not touch any further workflows.
For many lines, the bot could guess what happens if it only knew the main frame.

Therefore, I want to wrap up the SSIS project in a size that is less than 400000 characters so that I still have some chat left for the bot to answer.
How can I shrink down an SSIS project of many packages, with all of the setup files and a couple of packages, to have a dense input for the chat at hand?
PS: The code that I enter in the chat needs to be anonymized, that goes without saying.

Python code with Regexes to slim down the too huge SSIS project
I asked the chatbot to write a Python code and fitted that further to my needs. I know that AI generated answers are not allowed, but in this answer, it is not about the mere code or some bot answering my questions, but about my checked workflow to shrink down the SSIS project to a core that is understandable but small enough.
I crunched on the Regex for quite some hours, with many checks of the output, spending a lot of tokens.
I also checked the outcome by feeding the bot with the first 50000 characters of the full code of any bigger file, putting each against its slimmed down code and asking the bot to tell me what is in there that was not yet known. After that, I screened the code myself for the tools that SSIS projects of the company have most of the time to get a code that should work well enough on unseen SSIS projects, at least to such a good share that you need to change it only for seldom tools perhaps.
first_regex: One big trick is to get rid of a lot of repeated neutral system nodes ("inputColumn", "outputColumn") and instead get the true name behind it right away.
second_regex: The big trick that makes two thirds of the way is to fish the lines of the refId and all SQL code lines. That alone can already lead to a flawless but rough overview. Since I wanted to know not just a rough overview, but even the tiniest steps, I grew the Regex work to the three step Regex you see here.
third_regex: This is just a trick to drop the #-markers at the beginning of the marked lines again that help keeping the Regex slim. You might find a way to avoid such markers, but for me, it was enough to reach the aim. A Regex that does all in one go will bear a too huge overhead, if you can get there at all. The bot also agreed that it may not be the finest way to go, but the easiest, and it works while all of the one-Regex answers of the bot failed.
import os
import re
import json

def slim_down(content, code_marker):
    first_regex = re.compile(r'^\s+(?:<(?:input|output)Column[^s][\s\S\r\n]{0,2000}?)(^\s+(?:cachedName|name)="[^"]*")', re.MULTILINE)
    second_regex = re.compile(r'^\s*(<DTS:Executable|<DTS:Variable|.{0,4}refId(?![^>]*Columns[^>]*)|.*Join(?![^>].*Columns[^>]*)|.*Lookup(?![^>]*)|.*Split(?![^>].*Columns[^>]*)|.*EvaluationOrder|<component|<connection|<outputs|<inputColumn|<outputColumn|UITypeEditor="[^"]*">[\s\S]*?</property>|.*sortKeyPosition|specialFlags|name="Sql|SendMailTask|name="Destination|.*DestinationAction|name="PivotKey|#.*).*$', re.MULTILINE)
    third_regex = re.compile(r'#(\s{4})', re.MULTILINE)

    content_new = first_regex.sub(r'#\1', content)
    matches = second_regex.finditer(content_new)
    content_filtered = '\n'.join([match.group(0) for match in matches])
    content_final = third_regex.sub(r'\1', content_filtered)
    
    slimmed_down = content != content_final
    return f"\n{code_marker}\n{content_final}\n{code_marker}\n\n", slimmed_down

def anonymize_emails(content, email_map, file_path):
    email_regex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}')
    emails = email_regex.findall(content)

    dummy_counter = len(email_map) + 1

    for email in emails:
        if email not in email_map:
            dummy_email = f"dummy{dummy_counter}@dummy.com"
            email_map[email] = {
                "dummy": dummy_email,
                "files": {file_path: None}
            }
            dummy_counter += 1
        else:
            if file_path not in email_map[email]["files"]:
                email_map[email]["files"][file_path] = None
        
        content = content.replace(email, email_map[email]["dummy"])
    
    return content

def update_email_map(email_map, content, original_file_path, txt_file_path=None):
    for email, details in email_map.items():
        if details["dummy"] in content:
            if txt_file_path:
                details["files"][original_file_path] = txt_file_path
            else:
                if details["files"][original_file_path] is None:
                    details["files"][original_file_path] = f"no entry in '{original_file_path}'"

def ensure_final_file_only(email_map, combined_meta_content, output_meta_file):
    for email, details in email_map.items():
        for original_file_path in list(details["files"].keys()):
            if details["files"][original_file_path] is None or details["files"][original_file_path].startswith("no entry"):
                if details["dummy"] in combined_meta_content:
                    details["files"][original_file_path] = output_meta_file

def format_file_name(file, suffix):
    basename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    return f"{basename} {suffix}.txt"

def process_files(input_dir, output_dir, code_marker):
    meta_content = ""
    email_map = {}
    original_files_mapping = {}

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in ['.git', '.vs']]
        
        for file in files:
            if file in ['.gitattributes', '.gitignore']:
                continue
            
            input_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            
            with open(input_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                content = f.read()

            original_files_mapping[input_file_path] = input_file_path

            content = anonymize_emails(content, email_map, input_file_path)

            original_char_count = len(content)
            is_meta_file = not file.endswith('.dtsx')

            if is_meta_file:
                meta_content += f"{input_file_path} (originally {original_char_count}):\n{code_marker}\n{content}\n{code_marker}\n\n"
                update_email_map(email_map, content, input_file_path)
            else:
                slimmed_down = False
                if original_char_count > 30000:
                    filtered_content, slimmed_down = slim_down(content, code_marker)
                
                suffix = f"(originally {original_char_count})"
                if slimmed_down:
                    char_count = len(filtered_content)
                    suffix = f"(originally {original_char_count}, slimmed down {char_count})"
                    content_to_write = filtered_content
                else:
                    content_to_write = f"\n{code_marker}\n{content}\n{code_marker}\n\n"

                output_file_name = format_file_name(file, suffix)
                output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_file_name)

                with open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_f:
                    out_f.write(f"{input_file_path} {suffix}:{content_to_write}")

                original_files_mapping[input_file_path] = output_file_path

                update_email_map(email_map, content_to_write, input_file_path, output_file_path)
    
    if meta_content:
        meta_suffix = f"_{len(meta_content)}"
        output_meta_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"Meta{meta_suffix}.txt")

        with open(output_meta_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as meta_f:
            meta_f.write(meta_content.strip() + '\n')

        ensure_final_file_only(email_map, meta_content, output_meta_file)

    for email, details in email_map.items():
        for original_file_path in list(details["files"].keys()):
            if details["files"][original_file_path] is None or details["files"][original_file_path].startswith("no entry"):
                details["files"][original_file_path] = f"no entry in '{original_files_mapping[original_file_path]}'"
    
    email_map_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "email_map.json")

    # Save the JSON file as raw string and correctly display umlauts
    with open(email_map_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        raw_email_map = json.dumps(email_map, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
        raw_email_map = raw_email_map.replace("\\\\", "\\")
        f.write(raw_email_map)

def main():
    input_dir = input("Enter the input directory of the SSIS project: ").strip()
    output_dir = input("Enter the output directory: ").strip()

    code_marker = "```"

    input_dir = eval('r"{}"'.format(input_dir))
    output_dir = eval('r"{}"'.format(output_dir))
    
    if not os.path.exists(input_dir):
        print(f"The input directory '{input_dir}' does not exist.")
        return
    
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    
    process_files(input_dir, output_dir, code_marker)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The output:

an "email_map" file that maps any mails that were anonymized
all of the packages (slimmed down if needed) and one setup file with the rest of the project files (slimmed down if needed) put in just one file for a quick copy and paste.

I keep the code in full unless files are over 30,000 characters. I chose that border since the setup files were less than that so that I did not have to spend time on checking those setup files as well. My main aim was to slim down the huge package files instead. If you take the time for the checks of those setup files, you may set it to 10,000 and save some tokens, but do not set it to 0 without growing the Regex so that it eats connection managers, parameters and other things of the setup.
Output
I got a set of SSIS files of roughly 400,000 characters ready to be pasted in the chat. This copying and pasting takes just a little time since the Python code puts the tiny setup files in one big output file ready to be copied and pasted in one go.
The answer of the bot is good. The bot can deal with the slimmed down code as if it was the full project, I could not find any clear mistakes. It can show both the rough core and the tiny steps, both in C# and UML.
C# code
You can build an SSIS project in one C# script component. And C# is a language that can show much more than the mere SSIS workflow can tell you. That is why the C# code is the main trick.
The C#-Code seems most valuable as it can later be merged with the C# of other projects into one, which is the aim on top of this question. But that is not the question here, instead, it is the aim of another follow up question, see How do I merge scattered and intertwined projects from SSIS, stored procedures, and Access databases into one SSIS project with the help of a ChatGPT?. Whatever aim you have, C# is a good way to understand in full, without any gaps, what is going on in the SSIS package, for both the reader and the bot, and it can be put in an SSIS script component in a new SSIS project from where you can go on debugging and spreading it with SSIS tools or other SSIS C# script components to get to the good old graphical SSIS overview.
When asked to dive deeper into C#, the bot gave me a modularised code with an implemenation in classes.
UML

Activity Diagrams for the main package that steers the rest
Sequence Diagrams for the other packages
Component Diagrams for the main components an their links

UML and other tools
When I asked to dig deeper into UML and any tools of choice, I got:

Entity-Relationship-Diagramm (ERD)
State Diagram
Data Flow Diagram (DFD)
Detailed Transformations Logic

The bot's SSIS workflow is the best check against the graphical SSIS workflow at hand and whether the slimmed down files are understood well enough
I also asked for the SSIS workflow with all of the SQL code which turned out to be most helpful for the reader to check the work of the bot against the SSIS project itself. But that is more a thing to build up the best Regex. For the bot, the C#-Code together with the huge UML are more powerful since the but just understands the links and functions that it will need.
